# Get entries which are not assigned to a given id

Tags: mysql

I  have a n-n connected table and like to query the people who are **not** in either list **11** or **12**

*User*

```
ID | user
===========
 1 | Joe
 2 | Jane
 3 | Jim
 4 | Jack
```

*Lists*

```
 user_id | list_id
 =================
 1       | 10
 1       | 11
 1       | 12
 2       | 10
 2       | 12
 3       | 10
```

The result should be

```
3, Jim
4, Jack
```

I've tried

```
SELECT user.ID, user.name FROM user 
   LEFT JOIN user_lists ON user_id = user.ID AND user_id NOT IN (11, 12)
```

which obviously gives me *Jane* as well.

Comment: 1. Remove `NOT`.  2. Add `WHERE list_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner query should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, user FROM `User`
WHERE ID NOT IN 
   (SELECT user_id FROM `Lists` WHERE list_id IN (11, 12))
```

Fiddle as an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67933d/2